# PHP not returning immediately after proc_open()

Tags: php, jquery, html, linux, redis

I have 2 PHP scripts as `caller.php` and `task.php`. `caller.php` is called with JQuery Ajax request and then `caller.php` starts a process to run PHP file in background like the below code

**JQuery Ajax Request**

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/caller.php",
    type: "post",
    data: ""
  }).done(function(){}
});
```

**Caller.php**

```
$cmd = 'php task.php &';     // To call task.php in background
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array('pipe', 'r'),  // STDIN 
   1 => array('pipe', 'w'),  // STDOUT
   2 => array('pipe', 'w')   // STDERR
);
$pipes = array();

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

do {
    // get the pid of the child process and it's exit code
    $status = proc_get_status($process);
} while($status['running'] !== FALSE);

$pid = $status['pid'];
$exitcode = $status['exitcode'];

proc_close($process);

if($exitcode == 0){echo 'Task.php is running.';}
```

I learnt above code from [Running a php script via ajax, but only if it is not already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724120/running-a-php-script-via-ajax-but-only-if-it-is-not-already-running/15724165#15724165)

The above code works perfect but `proc_open()` waits until the `task.php` does not finish its job. I want `task.php` to run in background and get immediate response from `caller.php`.

I also tried `exec()` and `shell_exec()` but non of them worked. They wait `task.php` to do its complete job and then respond.

I also tried `xhr.abort()` in ajax to just leave the ajax response but later I found that `xhr.abort()` does not closes the connection with server.

Please note that I have trimmed the code and removed some basic session and user login etc steps to make the code shorter.

P.S. I have a VPS so, I have enough privileges to enable/disable php functions etc.

Comment: you'r already putting & at the end of your command so this will make it work in Background But i think that the do while loop that you added is what blocking your script caller.php.
you could just return the status to your ajax and do the test their.

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes I think you are right. Please hold on so I can check it.

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes Nop. That is not working evena after removing do-while block and putting the response direct.

Comment: hmm, weird. So if i understood correctly even after you remove it the loop and returning the status normally you will have as result in your ajax  $status['running'] == true ?

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes No Sir! Ajax is showing that the request is connected to server and still pending to receive response from server and when task.php finish the task in about 450 seconds then ajax shows the response from server

Answer (score 0):

ok i think you'r missing the flush() statement to return the status to ajax for example :

```
do {
    // get the pid of the child process and it's exit code
    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    echo $status['running'];
    ob_flush();flush(); // Send output to browser immediately

} while($status['running'] !== FALSE);
```

remember that if you use ob_flush() and flush() you will be getting the result not in the done function but in the xhr.onprogress  event  here is a example with explication https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've edited my response and added a link of example that could be useful to you.